# Train Pantograph IK Rig - Rotating armature in Object Mode changes pose

Tags: rigging, armature, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

I am a beginner with rigging in Blender. I have successfully created a rig to pose and animate a train pantograph using inverse kinematics. Now, I want to reposition and rotate the complete armature in object mode but this deforms the meshes incorrectly.

Here is the rig posed in its current position:

[image]

Now if I rotate the entire armature in object mode by 180 degrees so that the pantograph faces the  opposite direction, this is the result:

[image]

How do I change the armature so that I can rotate and move it freely, without it affecting the pose? I think that it has to do with some of the bone constraints I have used, but I am not sure.

Here is the .blend file:[image]

The pose is controlled by "control" bone about the y-axis.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *limit rotation* constraint was set to the world that's means your rig will be controlled by the world transformation. Check my screenshot it is set to *local*. Hope you get it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution. I had thought this was the problem but I did not change the rotation limits after selecting local.